# matplotlibcpp.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, matplotlib, gtk, gtk3, gtk#

I installed matplotlib for cpp in Ubuntu 16.04 but when I am including the matplotlibcpp.h in my code and then compiling it showing an error
command I am using for run my .cpp file is

```
g++ mtlb.cpp -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -lpython
```

**Error showing:**

> matplotlibcpp.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated with gtk+.

I am using sublime text editor for code. I dont know how to remove the error and make it to runnable.

I am working with gtk+ application and want to integrate matplotlib library to plot the visual data in the gtk+ gui. but its the next part of my project but the main point is to how to make matplotlib runnable for cpp environment.

*Note: please suggest any cpp free graph plotting library that can be easily integrated*

Comment: Is `matplotlibcpp.h` in ` /usr/include`? You might need to install a dev package

Comment: Hey @AlanBirtles the command I used to install was : 
`sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib python-numpy python2.7-dev`

Comment: I followed the tutorial of offcial repo:
[Github](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp?)

Comment: It states `The C++-part of the library consists of the single header file matplotlibcpp.h which can be placed anywhere.` where have you put the header?